# Is it possible to create a daily alert with a simple link to a lightning app in salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, mobilepush

I created a Lightning app (Salesforce1) which opens a custom VF page and does quite her her job. Only, the tab itself is not enough to push my colleagues to open it on a regular basis. So I would like a push notification (bell symbol in Salesforce1) which should be automatically triggered at a certain hour of the day and reporting just a link to open my Lightning app.
I looked around in visualforce developer forums and threads, but I was not able to even the answer to the question: "Is it possible to do so?"
Has someone an idea about it, and, if this is possible, how to implement it?
Thanks in advance for your help.
Cheers,
Francesco

Comment: I think this is with SFDC under consideration , its not implemented yet to push notifications in salesforce1                                                                                            check the ideas : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l0CIAAY

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, I had the feeling this was a part which was not covered yet but my research on the topic was probably not accurate enough.. I will follow the idea thread and put my thumbs up on it.. Francesco

Comment: It's worth noting that SF1 users get notifications for Chatter Posts. You could implement a post that happens daily.

Comment: Hello Christian, how?